# \uline with \hspace does not render at beginning of wrapped line

Tags: pdftex, ulem

Not sure what is going on. It seems that a `\uline` with only `\hspace` does not render if at the beginning of a wrapped line.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{ulem}

\geometry{a4paper, margin = 1in}

\begin{document}

This Non-Disclosure and Confidentially Agreement (the ``Agreement``) is entered into as of \uline{\hspace{1in}}, 20\uline{\hspace{0.5in}} (the ``Effective Date``) by and between:

\end{document}
```

Yes, I know I could achieve something similar with `\makebox[1in]{\hrulefill}` (would have to figure out how to lower it), but still curious why the `\uline` approach doesn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\hspace` does not produce any output at the beginning of a line (i.e., at a line break). This is usually what’s desired. To force output, you can write `\hspace*` rather than `\hspace` and get the output you wanted:

```
This Non-Disclosure and Confidentially Agreement (the ``Agreement``) is entered into as of \uline{\hspace*{1in}}, 20\uline{\hspace*{0.5in}} (the ``Effective Date``) by and between:
```

Comment: Thank you very much!